# trigger.io android 4.0+ not receiving pushing notifications

Tags: android, parsing, notifications, push, trigger.io

I was doing some testing and just realized that my android 4.0 devices are not receiving push notifications. I have received them in the past and Pars shows them being sent out but I do not get them.

I have older devices android 2.3 that are getting them just fine as well as IOS but android 4.0+ does not seem to be getting them.

Thanks.

Mike.

Comment: This might be related to an issue that was already reported on the Parse Q&A: https://parse.com/questions/android-push-notifications-not-arriving-without-force-stopping-pushservice-and-lockingunlocking-phone

Comment: All is well across my Android 4.x devices utilizing Parse push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

So I was doing some more testing and then all of a sudden the notifications started to come in on my android 4 + devices.

Now sure if this is just a slow network issue or not but seems to be working now.. strange.